# partially match a data.frame and subset all the data.frame

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

> ```
>  List_name     Condition1   Condition2  Situation1   Situation2
>   List1          0.01         0.12         66           123
>   List2          0.23         0.22         45           -34
>   List3          0.32         0.23         13           -12
>   List4          0.03         0.56         -3            45
>   List5          0.56         0.05         12           100
>   List6          0.90         0.09         22            32
> ```

I would like to filter each column "Condition" of the data.frame according to a cut off 0.5. 
After the filter, the subset will occur and will carry the corresponding value of columns "Situation". Filter and subset will work pairwise: "Condition1" with "Situation1", "Condition2" with "Situation2" and so on.

Just the desired output:

> ```
>  List_name     Condition1     Situation1  List_name  Condition2  Situation2
>   List1          0.01             66       List1        0.12        123
>   List2          0.23             45       List2        0.22        -34
>   List3          0.32             13       List3        0.23        -12
>   List4          0.03             -3       List5        0.05        100
>                                            List6        0.09         32
> ```

I'm pretty sure that there's probably another similar situation posted before but I searched and I didn't find it.

Comment: What if if condition is met in Condition1 and not condition2...for example List4? You will take the 4the line for all situations? I dnt'see column Situation2..is this a type error?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I made a mistake! I edit!

Comment: Why is List4 in the output list? Condition2 there is 0.56, which is > 0.5.

Comment: @Fuv8 sorry maybe I miss something but I don't see your edit.

Comment: Just edited now! Hope this can help!

Comment: What should be in the blanks you've shown?  A numeric vector cannot have a blank.  And why have you excluded `List6`?

Comment: Guys! See the final edit. It is what exactly I need. Sorry for multiple edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the notion that boolean checks are vectorized:

```
x <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2)
x < 0.5
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

And some `grep` results:

```
grep('Condition', names(DF1))
```

To do this subsetting you can use `apply` to generate your boolean vector:

```
keepers <- apply(DF1[, grep('Condition', names(DF1))], 1, function(x) any(x < 0.5))
```

And subset:

```
DF1[keepers,]
```

Notice that this doesn't necessarily return the data structure you showed in your question.  But you can alter the anonymous function accordingly using `all` or a different threshold value.

---

In lieu of the edits, I would approach this differently.  I would use `melt` from the `reshape2` package:

```
library(reshape2)
dat.c <- melt(DF1, 
              id.var='List_name', 
              measure.var=grep('Condition', names(DF1), value=TRUE),
              variable.name='condition',
              value.name='cond.val')
dat.c$idx <- gsub('Condition', '', dat.c$condition)
dat.s <- melt(DF1, 
              id.var='List_name', 
              measure.var=grep('Situation', names(DF1), value=TRUE),
              variable.name='situation',
              value.name='situ.val')
dat.s$idx <- gsub('Situation', '', dat.s$situation)
dat <- merge(dat.c, dat.s)

out <- dat[dat$cond.val < 0.5,]

   List_name idx  condition cond.val  situation situ.val
1      List1   1 Condition1     0.01 Situation1       66
2      List1   2 Condition2     0.12 Situation2      123
3      List2   1 Condition1     0.23 Situation1       45
4      List2   2 Condition2     0.22 Situation2      -34
5      List3   1 Condition1     0.32 Situation1       13
6      List3   2 Condition2     0.23 Situation2      -12
7      List4   1 Condition1     0.03 Situation1       -3
10     List5   2 Condition2     0.05 Situation2      100
12     List6   2 Condition2     0.09 Situation2       32
```

You can then use `dcast` to put the data back in the initial format if you want, but I find data in this "long" form much easier to work with.  This form is also pleasant since it avoids the need for NA values where you have rows where one condition is met and others are not.

```
out.c <- dcast(out, List_name ~ condition, value.var='cond.val')
out.s <- dcast(out, List_name ~ situation, value.var='situ.val')
merge(out.c, out.s)

  List_name Condition1 Condition2 Situation1 Situation2
1     List1       0.01       0.12         66        123
2     List2       0.23       0.22         45        -34
3     List3       0.32       0.23         13        -12
4     List4       0.03         NA         -3         NA
5     List5         NA       0.05         NA        100
6     List6         NA       0.09         NA         32
```

Comment: HI Justin! Thanks a lot for your help!nevertheless after pasting both :out.c <- dcast(out, List_name ~ condition, value.var='cond.val') and out.s <- dcast(out, List_name ~ situation, value.var='situ.val') this appears:  "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length". What does it mean? Reshape is totally new for me.

Comment: It means one of those two commands has duplicated rows (combinations of `List_name` and `condition`).

Comment: Hi Justin! It works very well! I think reshape2 is a very powerful library! thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to excellent @Arun solution, but based on columns names and without any assumption.

```
cols.conds <- colnames(dat)[gregexpr(pattern='Condition[0-9]+',colnames(dat)) > 0]
lapply(cols.conds, function(x){
   col.list <- colnames(dat)[1]
   col.situ <- gsub('Condition','Situation',x)
   dat[which(dat[[x]] < 0.5), c(col.list,x,col.situ)]}
)
```

I assume dat is :

```
dat <- read.table(text =' List_name     Condition1   Condition2  Situation1   Situation2
  List1          0.01         0.12         66           123
  List2          0.23         0.22         45           -34
  List3          0.32         0.23         13           -12
  List4          0.03         0.56         -3            45
  List5          0.56         0.05         12           100
  List6          0.90         0.02         22            32',head=T)
```

Comment: agstudy, sorry..the final edit will help you to understand. Sorry again for multiple edits.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking for is attainable, but it can't be `bind`(bound) in the way you've shown as they have unequal elements. So, you'll get a list.

Here, I assume that your `data.frame` always is of the form `List_name`, followed by a list of `Condition1`, ... ,`ConditionN` and then `Situation1`, ..., `SituationN`.

Then, this can be obtained by getting the `ids` first and then filtering using `lapply`

```
ids <- grep("Condition", names(df))
lapply(ids, function(x) df[which(df[[x]] < 0.5), c(1,x,x+length(ids))])

# [[1]]
#   List_name Condition1 Situation1
# 1     List1       0.01         66
# 2     List2       0.23         45
# 3     List3       0.32         13
# 4     List4       0.03         -3
# 
# [[2]]
#   List_name Condition2 Situation2
# 1     List1       0.12        123
# 2     List2       0.22        -34
# 3     List3       0.23        -12
# 5     List5       0.05        100
# 6     List6       0.09         32
```